# What is the best way to composite several rectangle structs together into one large rectangle

Tags: algorithm, shapes, rectangles

Say I have 2 rectangles (originX, originY, width, height)

0,0,100,100

100,100,100,100

What is the best way to get the rectangle that contains both?

i.e: 0,0,200,200

Here is a crappy paint picture to illustrate what I mean

[image]

**My plan now is to:

1) Find the smallest origin, that is the origin of the return rect

2) Find the highest originY+height, that is the upper bound of the return rect

3) Find the highest originX+width, that is the right bound of the return rect**

But my issue is that there could potentially be thousands of rectangles, so I want to make sure I have the best solution

I think I'm having a hard time finding a solution because I'm wording this poorly.  In my mind, this would be something like compositing rectangles-- but is there another way to describe what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what, you will have to look at each rectangle to achieve you answer. If you fail to look at even one, you could miss a point that is outside of your bounds. So no matter what the best solution you can find will be O(n).

Since we are looking for an O(n) solution, it is pretty simple: just iterate over each rectangle. Store the minimum and maximum x and y found so far. Note that maximum x and y are defined in this case by `originX + width` and `originY + height`. After iterating over all rectangles, the rectangle formed by the points `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, `maxY` will be your solution.